# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with 1/lnx

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm struggling with this problem, because I'm not sure how to integrate $1/\ln(x)$

> Suppose that you have the following information about a function
>   $F(x)$:
>
> $$F(0)=1, F(1)=2, F(2)=5$$ $$F'(x)=\frac1{\ln(x)}$$
>
> Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus evaluate  $$\int_0^2
>  \frac2{\ln(x)}$$

Comment: $1/\ln x$ is not defined at $x=1$, and if you defined it, it wouldn't be continuous at this point.

Comment: Not that it matters for this exercise, but the data are inconsistent. $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ has a non-integrable singularity at $1$.

Comment: Yes, that is a bit puzzling. I wasn't sure what to make about that.

Comment: The question would be better posed if the $\ln(x)$ were replaced by a generic $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to know how to integrate $1/\ln x$ (which is good, because it doesn't have an elementary antiderivative). You do need to know the numerical values of an antiderivative of $1/\ln x$ at the endpoints of the interval.

Do you know them?

Comment: Is the answer just F(b) - F(a)? Which would be 5-1=4?

Comment: @Aaron: What about the $2$ in the numerator?

Comment: @robjohn Would that make it 8, because you can move the constant outside of the integral and then multiply it after you use the FTC?

Comment: @Aaron: that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If $F'$ were continous on $[0,2]$ we had
$$
I = 2 \int\limits_0^2\!\! F'(x) \, dx = 2 (F(2) - F(0)) = 2(5-1) = 8
$$
Alas this problem seems buggy, because of the singularity at $x=1$.